# Pentagon ABCDE has AB = BC = CD = DE, angle ABC = angle BCD = 108°, and angle CDE = 168°. Find the measure of angle BEA in degrees.

Tags: geometry

An image of the question:
[image]

In the solution given in the source, there is an equilateral triangle created by taking f such that angle BCF is 108 but I can't find the equilateral triangle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a regular pentagon $AB$ that lies on points $A, B, H$ (drew in blue colour).

By the regular pentagon, you can find that $\triangle$ FDE is equilateral.

Draw segments $AE, CE$ By this you can get $\triangle CDE \cong \triangle AEF$ (S.A.S.)

As $\triangle CDE \cong \triangle AEF, CE=AE$

Now look at $\triangle BAE, \triangle BEC$ they are congruent (S.S.S)

Then you can see that the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ is BE.

As $\triangle FAE$ is isosceles you can get the $\angle FAE=6^o$. Then $\angle BAE = 108-6=102$

Similarly, you can find that $x=180-54-102=24^o$

[image]